# How to fix Windows 7 boot loader

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, debian

I recently installed debian 7 after booting it from my pen drive. Then i did some mistake while installing it. Well, Debian is not installed. And when I rebooted my system it says- No boot device found.

Then I installed ubuntu 12, after installing it on my second separate partition, I rebooted after I installed ubuntu in it.

After rebooting, boot manager of ubuntu opened up, option of windows7 also came up, i selected that option and my windows 7 opened up successfully, and I formated my whole drive which contained ubuntu. My question is- How to delete ubuntu boot manager and install windows boot manager?

Comment: You could possibly resolve this using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/). [This article](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/tips-and-tricks/recovering-windows-bootloader/) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need — repair Windows boot loader.

1. Boot From the ***Windows Installation Disc***
2. The first thing you’ll need to do is boot off the install disc, and then click through until you see the "***Repair your computer***" link in the lower left-hand corner.
   [image]
3. You’ll need to choose the correct installation of Windows and then click the ***Next*** button.
   [image]
4. And then you’ll get to the System Recovery Options screen.
   [image]
5. Choose "***Startup repair. Automatically fix problems...***" option and click ***Continue***
6. Choose your Windows installation drive’s letter (usually C:) and click on ***Automated Repair***
7. Easy Recovery Essentials will now begin to fix the error automatically.

---

**If** start-up repair **cannot repair** your computer automatically return to **4** - You need manually repairing the Master Boot Record

1. Choose "***Command Prompt***" options.
2. You need restore the master boot record. Simply type in the following command:

   > bootrec /fixmbr
3. Then you need write a new boot sector onto the system partition with this command (which is often more useful):

   > bootrec /fixboot
4. And then

   > bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
5. And of course, if you just use bootrec /? you’ll be able to see all the options.

[image]

Comment: well.... i have hp pavilion g6 laptop, i have system repair dvd of my system. However, I tried to do this through windows 7 installation disk, i clicked on Repair your computer link but it shows there is not any operating system installed. :( And I don't want to factory reset my computer, is there any tool that boots from bios

Comment: Choose Command Prompt and write: **bootrec /fixmbr** then **bootrec /fixboot** and **bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd**

Comment: On which of the items above, message "... not installed ..." was reported?

Comment: my machine is preinstalled with win7 home edition 64 bit and i have installer disk of win7 ultimate 32 bit. That's why it didn't detect already installed os on my machine.

Comment: being very specific-
is it possible to get into my system through linux live cd. And can i edit bootmanager from there?

Comment: Yes, you can load linux live CD and edit Grub settings. But Grub stay as boot loader.